# How to Append Options to command (bash)

Tags: bash

I added some aliases to ~/.bashrc to simplify my work environment, but I would like to know how to append Options on command read.

For example, I added:

```
alias emacs="emacs -nw"
```

to be able to stop writing the `no window` command every time I run a file.

I would like to know if there's some documentation on appending options on command read. For example instead of adding an `alias` which is not elegant to me (Of course coding style is personal taste) we would just write something like

```
if (command == "emacs") {
    command += "-nw"
}
```

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use an alias? That's literally precisely what they're for.

Comment: @Kevin I think sometimes options have to be added at the end of the command, I want to pré solve that

Comment: You can use a function. No need to hook into every command.

Comment: @Kevin Ok great, I'll use functions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete answer on how I solved this with the comments suggestions:

I made a small bash function to compile C programs by taking in argument the name of the c file and usually use the same name without the .c for compiled executable.

```
function ccompile(){
    cc -std=c99 -Wall $1.c -o $1 -lm
}
```

What this will do, it will take my first argument ($1), fill in the $1s in the function and compile it's code to an executable file with the same name, for example if we type:

```
ccompile hello_world
```

it will fill the command and have

```
cc -std=c99 -Wall hello_world.c -o hello_world -lm
```

This can also be used for my emacs problem, for example:

```
function emacs(){
    emacs -nw $1
}
```

This question was basically asked because I like scalable things and I was sure that alias is not enough to solve this kind of problems, we couldn't use alias for the compiling script I needed.